# Two many rainbows?

Tags: geometry, visual, science, real, paradox

Wish I’d had a camera at the time
but a cartoon will have to suffice,
representing two actual incomplete rainbows
that stop in midair where they meet,
lit only by a setting sun.

[image]

This seemed so paradoxical,
I honestly wondered if it was a dream.
After all, on a normal
[rainbow with two arches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Full_featured_double_rainbow_at_Savonlinna_1000px.jpg),
the arcs do not touch
and the larger one is very much fainter with a reversed spectrum.
The arches schematized here were indeed accompanied by
typically-faint concentric larger arcs
that also stopped abruptly where they, too, met,
exactly above the main meeting point.

Being awake, as it turned out,
I discovered the simple explanation for this,
related to an often-subtle
and less dramatic everyday phenomenon
that is readily understandable in nonscientific terms.
I had enough information at the time
to solve this like a puzzle, though,
and now you do too.

**What was that simple explanation for this odd pair of rainbows?**

**Notes.**
Only air was between the point of view and these rainbows.
The less complete rainbow, to the right, is *slightly* brighter
and both arches brighten the air directly below them.
The picture has been **revised** to more clearly represent
how the rainbows end at slightly different places, muddled by their overlap.
 
The larger arch ends
a little to left (and slightly up) from where the smaller arch ends.
 
The rainbows were not as thick as depicted (none are)
and had further characteristic features
that scientific photography would reveal
to extend a vertical pattern of similar meeting points.
 
Safe to guess that this effect was not observed
by humans more than a century or two ago,
although tiny animals may have experienced it
over the course of eons.
 
Some details of the real-life story have been altered
in an attempt to stymie internet searches.

Here is an **added** diagram meant to emphasize
that the position of a rainbow depends on the direction of
incoming sunlight
and
that the size and distance of any rainbow are intrinsically ambiguous
because the mist that creates a rainbow is rarely at a single
distance and the resulting image occupies the same portion of
the visual field
regardless of actual distances to individual mist droplets.
More information can be found all over the internet,
such as
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow)
and (less laboriously)
[earthsky.org](http://earthsky.org/earth/what-gives-rainbows-their-curved-shape).

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What exactly is the puzzle here? Do you want to know the science behind a real life phenomenon? Well, if that's the case Ian is right.

Comment: The science is known, @ABcDexter, the situation is unusual and paradoxical, although people can see it many times a year if they plan right

Comment: What is the 'paradox' here? Is it related to the superposition of two rainbows, one being brighter than the other ?

Comment: Both that there are two and that they stop in midair can be bewildering

Comment: Ok, if i get back to my senses, i will try to 'solve' it :)

Comment: It seems the puzzle is to determine "where on Earth" such a phenomenon could take place. I haven't asked this yet, but the more faded rainbow is the traditional 145 degree angle where the brighter one is a steeper angle. I think these _might_ be important clues in the puzzle, but maybe not. Reflection rainbows that come together (I'm not a rainbow expert) usually come together on the ground/water. So, understanding the physics would seem quite helpful, but once understood may narrow down its location. The century clue lends to man-made, but that's just a guess. I think it's at least puzzling.

Comment: Good for recognizing a puzzle and clues when you see them, @John ,
and a career physicist would have little if any advantage over most people here. Quite right about a human-made component, although tiny animals may have seen seen the same effect over the course of eons and written poetry about it. Your reasoning has a good chunk of this figured out and seems on the verge of getting the whole story. The mention of other concentric arcs, though, was meant to exclude the role of wider (or narrower) secondary rainbows,
which was what I first thought on the scene but quickly found out otherwise.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/is-this-puzzle-like-a-mathematics-exercise) about the on-topicness or off-topicness of this question.

Comment: A real life puzzle supercedes a contrived one every time. I still can't figure this one out. :)

Comment: It seems that a logical conclusion would be a very large raindrop. It certainly does not occur naturally, and tiny animals would be able to see it as water drops on surfaces e.g. dew.

Comment: Come to think of it, @somebody, a raindrop seems entirely capable of fostering this effect for animals even tinier than I had imagined. You'd get my vote of approval for an answer like that, even if it is not complete otherwise.

Comment: Since it isn't the answer I figured I would at least show some cool photos as I eliminated the Louvre and Chicago's cloud gate. http://i0.wp.com/www.sistavoyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/louvre1.jpg and http://assets.thecreatorsproject.com/blog_article_images/images/000/024/389/6850408565_ab9afd676b_z_detail_em.jpg

Comment: If it wasn't  "lit only by a setting sun" I'd guess you were sitting in a car.

Comment: Amazing, @Sleafar, that's exactly where I was, and had to go outside to make sure that wasn't causing it (also to make sure I wasn't hallucinating and couldn't drive; it really confused me)

Comment: Well, the headlights would possibly be an explanation, if there wasn't the quote from my previous comment. And btw., [who cares about double rainbows](http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1134738-double-rainbow)? ;)

Comment: It's almost as if you had been there, @Sleafar, in which case you might have also pointed out an error in the puzzle statement/picture that I'm about to mention in an update. Right, though, the sun was providing all the light that came into play.

Comment: Oboy, @John, bounty's coming due. Thanks again for putting it up! Two answers are almost-equally well on the way to completion, though, so I'll start a second bounty (tried already but system doesn't seem to allow simultaneity) for the answer that doesn't get yours. I might also add a diagram to complete the solution you go with, if the poster agrees.

Comment: @humn, righto. No problem! I was going to ask you which answer you like or let it auto-bounty, but I'll just set it to the top answer.

Comment: @John - But ... but ... but ... mine wasn't a real answer ... how did I get the bounty!?!??!

Comment: Your answer has the most pieces of the solution and came first, @YowE3K. Mind if I add a diagram or two? CiaPan seemed on the way to figuring out the complete solution from scratch but didn't follow through and will get another bounty in recognition.

Comment: I'm more than happy for you to add a diagram or two.  Or I should a make it a "community wiki"?

Comment: I thought the points would be lost too, @YowE3K, but a similar maneuver yesterday didn't seem to do that. Don't know about the bounty. No rush to wikify in any case, certainly not before the added diagram(s), and your fairmindedness is on record.

Comment: @YowE3K, and humn, I'm not positive but I think it would have auto-awarded anyway. I was curious what it would do actually :). I believe it would've gone to you. Anyway I don't see why it wouldn't remain awarded to you.

Comment: Well aimed, @John, looks like it might have been auto-awarded to a different answer because of [timing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95040/313009)

Comment: The complete situation is now outlined in the
[community wiki answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44599/18129),
@John.
Thanks again for your interest!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Original solution by YowE3K**
 
(who later turned it into this community wiki)

This isn't an answer to the exact question, but the following link is to an image that I thought was worth looking at anyway:

> http://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/bowim6.htm
>   
>   [image]

And @justhalf found another image which looks even more like the one in the question, except rotated 90 degrees:

> [image]
>   
>   [Atmospheric Optics](http://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/bowim47.htm)

---

I'm thinking that the **actual answer** is something to do with

> light **reflecting** off the **windows** of a **high-rise building**

---

**Added** layout from puzzle’s poser

> The rightmost diagram represents what can happen when
>  the **sun** sets in a direction almost parallel
>  to the wall of a **high-rise building**
>  (whose corner is the gray rectangular area with writing)
>  and **reflects** off its **windows**.
>  A second rainbow is created by the sun’s reflection,
>  as if there were a second sun,
>  but neither rainbow’s right half is illuminated
>  for different reasons.
>  
>  •
>      A portion of sunlight for the directly-lit rainbow
>      is blocked by the building.
>  
>  •
>      Reflected sunlight that would complete
>      the second rainbow (dimmer and left shifted)
>      is not present due to
>      the viewpoint’s position
>      and the sun’s angle.
>  
>
>  The building’s *vertical* wall plays the same reflective role
>  as *horizontal* bodies of water in the
>  photographs above, which is why the doubling
>  is oriented 90° differently.
>  
>  [image]

For comparison, shadows are often doubled in a related manner:

[image]

Comment: This explains why the larger bow is fainter.  If we imagine that there's a mirror to the right, perpendicular to the screen, with the Sun behind us and to the left; then the reflection of the Sun would be to the right, and the (dimmer) reflection rainbow would appear to the left of the main bow.  (And the rainbows would disappear where they were shadowed by the mirrored object on the right.)

Comment: This one fits the image better: http://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/bowim47.htm

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice your comment until now, @2012rcampion, but it would make a valuable addition to the body of this post.

Comment: Good find, @justhalf, YowE3K and you have found two of the pictures I had hoped would be more elusive, but they are still different enough to keep things interesting.

Comment: You're really zeroing in on the complete answer, YowE3K. If you get much closer I might just be tempted to butt in with the last detail or two (perhaps a diagram). The rest is more a matter of geometry than physics and @2012rcampion probably has that part figured out in even more detail than shows in the comment.

Comment: @humn - I haven't done anything since my original "answer" (other than to edit my "answer" to include the extra image found by justhalf).  And my original "answer" was more just a comment re the nice images which I found which were somewhat similar to the image in the question than an attempt to solve the "puzzle".

Comment: Your recent 90-degree observation is a crucial piece of the complete solution. I hope you don't wind up feeling too pressured to fill out what began as a  somewhat casual comment.

Comment: @humn - Your recent "clues" re water have been making me think of something like light refracting off a glass enclosed swimming pool / aquarium.  I am dying to find out what the actual answer ends up being!

Comment: @humn - Finding answers to this question is certainly causing me to find some extremely pretty examples of rainbows!!  (I just found one where the rainbow is vertical.)  (And now one where the rainbow stops mid-air http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lunar_Rainbow_3_-_ORION_L_-_Victoria_Falls_-_Calvin_Bradshaw_3-1024x768.jpg - oops - actually that is a moonbow, not a rainbow.)

Comment: @YowE3K That link is a 404 error for me; to get it to work you can try linking it using markdown link syntax (which works in comments too): [`[one where the rainbow stops mid-air](http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lunar_Rainbow_3_-_ORION_L_-_Victoria_Falls_-_Calvin_Bradshaw_3-1024x768.jpg)`](http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lunar_Rainbow_3_-_ORION_L_-_Victoria_Falls_-_Calvin_Bradshaw_3-1024x768.jpg)

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works. (Ps. I added that great moonbow picture to a gallery post here.)

Comment: See how well your conclusion matched the situation after all, @YowE3K?
(Glad to see you didn't lose any points by wikifying!)

Comment: @humn - :) I guess I am going to have to start going outside at sunset (or sunrise) more often - but first I am going to have to find a building at juuuust the right orientation!  And, obviously, a different building for every day of the year.  (P.S.  I am fairly amazed that I actually understood the explanation - I was expecting it to be more complicated than that even though your question stated it wasn't.)

Answer (score 8):

I can't see images now, but from the optics laws ang geometry it follows that the center point of the rainbow's arc is opposite to the light source with respect to your eye. In other words, if the rainbow is directly in front of you, the Sun is directly behind you. If you see two rainbows intersecting, you must have two suns behind you, relatively close to one another.

If one rainbow arc was *above* the other, its respective light source must have been *below* the other one. If the arcs were side-by-side, the two suns were at the same height.

Probably one of them was a reflection of the original one in quite a big, almost flat surface. Did you have a lake, or a glass-covered sky-scraper behind you or in front of you when seeing the two rainbows?

Comment: Have you had access to the image yet? It might trigger a change in your current concluding question.

Comment: What do you mean "had access to the image"? What image?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan: The image in the puzzle, which CiaPan hadn't seen when writing the answer (based on just the words of the puzzle, I guess, wish I had described it more thoroughly).

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't actually see anything in the answer that would be invalidated by looking at your image -- except, I suppose, that it doesn't address the "stopping in mid-air" bit which is a particularly striking feature of your rainbows. (But which is also clearly mentioned in the question text.)

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Comment: I continue to be amazed by the astuteness of this answer without your even seeing the picture, CiaPan. If you don't intend to complete this, I plan to set a bounty  in recognition and to add a missing piece to an earlier almost-complete solution.

Comment: The complete situation is now outlined in the
[community wiki answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44599/18129),
@CiaPan, so you can see just how accurate you were.
A bounty of recognition will reach your answer in a few days.

Answer (score 3):

If it is only lit by the setting sun

> I would guess that the second one came from the sun's reflection from the moon.
>  Since the sun was setting, odds are the moon was starting to show up already.
>  And since it's only the reflection of the sun, it would explain the different intensity of the colors.
>  Since the light's point of origin is different, it would explain the different angle of the rainbow. 
>  For the 2 rainbows which came from 2 completely opposite source of lights to be generated in a cross arc like this must be very rare indeed.

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this answer might be stupid but thought to give a try. Is it

> Prism based rainbow?

Explanation

> *on a normal rainbow with two arches, the arcs do not touch and the larger one is very much fainter with a reversed spectrum.* These lines some how tells that it's not a normal/natural rainbow which you tried producing using two prisms. One created a normal looking rainbow while the other created the brighter one. Reason being, there is a little pink color in the rainbow which can be produced due to red and violet combination. Phenomenon may be called **"Dispersion of light"** Also with small animals and insects the phenomenon called **"Visible spectrum"** comes naturally.

Comment: ^vote with a note: Interesting take, with a bonus lesson about nature. The pink you mention might be my last-minute touchup attempt to fade to uncolored sky but the edges of the rainbow still have too much contrast to be realistic. (Had to learn a new graphics system just to get the overlapped parts to come out as anything but utterly bizarre.)

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a

> solar eclipse.

Not sure about the science of it, but here's a shot.

> The moon blocks out let's say half of the sun, so only half of the rainbow from the sun is seen. Then there is a secondary but dimmer rainbow coming from the reflected light from the moon, which due to the moon being closer has a wider arc. The only source of light is still the sun, but some is being reflected by the moon. And as to the history of them, maybe people only figured out how to view them without being blinded within the past couple centuries.

Comment: ^vote for taking into account so many parts of the puzzle. Turns out, though, that a partial sun produces just as much of a rainbow as a full sun, only dimmer.

Comment: What if

>! It was also very windy, such that the rain drops are flattened. The shape of the rainbow corresponds to the shape of the rain drops, so if the wind makes the drops essentially hemispheres, then the bow would be  half of an arc.

Comment: Woops the spoiler didn't work. New to this stuff. Any way to delete/edit that last comment?

Comment: @Spuds, glad this was at least asked. But I thought wouldn't create the crisp demarcation necessary.

Comment: Super interesting idea about irregular drops, $@$Spuds and @John. Can imagine how that would kinda work.

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another try.

> You woke up on a boat. This explains why you thought it was a dream. The image is sideways of what it would be from the perspective of someone standing upright. The sea was calm so it reflected the second, dimmer part. As to the recent (last couple hundred years) aspect, this phenomenon may occur at extreme latitudes. All the pictures I've come across were from places very north. It was mentioned in comments that there is a human made component, which I think is climate change. There is now more (calm) sea up north so it is plausible to wake up to a reflected rainbow.

"tiny animals may have experienced it over the course of eons and written poetry about it"

> The earth's last warm period before some old ice age? This is still confusing. Were creatures smaller back then? Did they write poetry?

Sorry for answering twice but it's a completely separate thought.

Edit:

> They don't line up because the actual reflection is happening past the horizon.

Comment: (Removing the schlocky wisecrack about poetry from the puzzle statement.)

Comment: Your "Edit:" idea could provide a very mysterious premise for a future puzzle.

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

We know from the other answers, that ...

> ... two light sources are needed to create two non-concentric rainbows. We also know from the other answers, that one of the light sources must be left or right from the other.
>
>  The first thing that came to my mind were the headlamps of a car, but the question states, that the sun was the only light source. However, the OP confirmed that he was sitting in a car when he saw the rainbows for the first time. One possible explanation would be, that the low standing sun was reflected by two things on the car. This could be either the headlamps (not sure if this would work) or the side mirrors. In the latter case the OP could see the rainbows in the inner mirror while sitting in the car. The rainbows would stop in mid air, because the light is reflected in the form of cones.

Comment: OP also said that "Only air was between the point of view and these rainbows", so it wouldn't be seen through a mirror.

Comment: I took this to mean that the sunlight itself might have been reflected by the car's mirror, which I can imagine producing an interesting effect on a smaller-than-human scale

Comment: @Spuds He also said "that's exactly where I was, and had to go outside to make sure that wasn't causing it".

Answer (score 1):

You could be

> At Niagara Falls (or at a place with multiple waterfalls)

Because

> Waterfalls can create rainbows:
> [image]
> But where there are multiple waterfalls, two rainbows could be created, one behind the other, so if you positioned yourself just right then they would appear to touch. One rainbow is slightly brighter because it is closer.

And

> They are cut off as they go into the waterfall

Comment: ^vote with a note: This is where physics/geometry pulls a fast one, as the rainbows would always line up, just as if the one in front were smaller as well. The apparent size and position of a rainbow depends only on our relationship to the sun rather than on the exact position of the reflecting mist, as long as there is some mist at some distance in the right direction(s). Thanks for the gorgeous picture too!

Comment: Sorry to report a mistake with the rainbows' meeting point in the picture. The puzzle statement has been revised and a new picture is in the works.

Answer (score 1):

> Could this be something to do with wearing spectacles/bifocals and seeing one through plain air and other through glasses unless spectacles violate the "only air" assumption

Comment: ^vote with a note: Yes, eyeware is meant to be excluded by the "only air..." phrase, but now I want to see a rainbow through [3D-glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D#Complementary_color)!

Answer (score 0):

Community gallery of almost-answers, begun from comments— feel free to add.

Moonbow that stops mid-air 
[image]

<sup>https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lunar_Rainbow_3_-_ORION_L_-_Victoria_Falls_-_Calvin_Bradshaw_3.jpg</sup>

Carrousel du Louvre, Paris 
[image]

<sup>https://i0.wp.com/www.sistavoyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/louvre1.jpg</sup>

Cloud Gate, Chicago 
[image]

<sup>https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvbn.jpg</sup>

Who cares about double rainbows? 
[image]

<sup>http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1134738-double-rainbow</sup>

Run-of-the-mill everyday double rainbow 
[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6d/Full_featured_double_rainbow_at_Savonlinna_1000px.jpg))</sub>

<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Full_featured_double_rainbow_at_Savonlinna_1000px.jpg</sup>

Low antisolar point 
[image]

<sup>https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhI4b.jpg</sup>

Comment: (Some of these might not be 100% unaltered)