# Another visual puzzle with slightly more trivia. Good luck!

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge

A single word connects all of these images:

[image: The Sea or an Ocean]

[image: A Rainbow]

[image: Gimli; a character from The Lord of the Rings]

[image: A Super-cute Sloth]

[image: A rescued BORG; from the TV show Star Trek Voyager]

[image: The Pyramid of Giza]

[image: A Zip]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How appropriate that there are...

> ...7 pictures...

...as what are pictured are...

> ...allusions to **the number 7**.

Picture by picture
 
(trail-of-clues commentary tagged on in response to a comment) **:**

1. > One of the
   >  [**7** seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Seas).

The initial hunch from pictures 5 and 6 was reinforced by this
  ↑  
ocean and that
  ↓  
rainbow, in particular, whose details are still fresh from dealing with
[*Two many rainbows?*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44597/two-many-rainbows).

2. > A rainbow with
   >  [**7** nominal colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROYGBIV).
3. > [Gimli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimli_(Middle-earth)),
   >  from *The Lord of the Rings*,
   >  
   >  <del>“a remote descendant of Durin the Deathless,
   >  chief of the **7** Fathers of
   >  the Dwarves.”</del>
   >  **a dwarf**, which brings to mind
   >  [*Snow White and
   >    the **7** Dwarfs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Dwarfs).

(   ↑  
  Saved for last, using pure image look-up and word searching.
  Got **l u c k y** !
  Clues like this are the most thrilling,
  when they fit into place, that is.)

4. > [A sloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth),
   >  named after one of the
   >  [**7** capital/deadly sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth_(deadly_sin)),
   >  also featured as scary graffiti in
   >  [the movie *Se**7**en*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_(1995_film)).

↑  
That face keeps showing up at the ends of some of the more
[unusual mammalian necks](http://www.livescience.com/10178-freak-nature-sloth-rib-cage-bones-neck.html)
in nature documentaries.
It took the suggestiveness of other clues to
think of the thematic connection,
but there it was.

5. > [**7** of Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine),
   >  a reformed Borg in the TV series *Star Trek Voyager*.

↑  
This was the clue that got me going
as, fortunately, I could only remember the name of the character
but not of the actor.
So the pyramid
  ↓  
compounded that into a hunch.

6. > Khufu’s pyramid at Giza, one of the
   >  **7** Wonders of the
   >  [Ancient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonders_of_the_World#Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World) **/** Modern World.

> **7.**    A zipper, as in
>  [the compressor/archiver **7**-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip).

As for this puzzle’s title:

> **7** is considered a number that brings...

...“Good luck!”

Comment: How did you get this within.. what 10 minutes of posting? Really, what were your major leads/hunches and which followed afterwards?

Comment: You're right, @zahbaz, I should recount the trail of clues in the solution. I happened to recognize the TV character and the pyramid, so they got me going. And had I realized how fresh this puzzle was, I wouldn't have tried because someone else would have surely posted first.

Comment: @humn Why not? If you found it first, post it first!

Comment: @BrentHackers Is that really the logic for the third picture? I figured it was a reference to Snow White's dwarfs.

Comment: @ScottM the simplest solution is usually the right one, especially where I'm concerned... +1

Comment: Answer has been updated, thank you @Scott M!